# Difference between proposing a research framework and research approach

Tags: writing, writing-style, terminology

I would like to get some concrete examples as to what is the difference between saying that I am presenting a research framework and a research approach.

Take the field of robotics or any other engineering field for example. People do all kinds of field experiments and simulations. Different papers may have a different ratio of mixing of the two. Some may also be theoretical.

So what kind of paper would fall in the category of the research framework and what kind of paper will fall in the category of research approach? Because I have confusion when writing a paper, should I say I am presenting a framework or an approach?

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with any real difference. Do you have evidence that they aren't just different terms for the same thing? Framework a bit more specific than an approach, perhaps.

Comment: I also think that framework is just a stronger word for approach. But I just wanted clarification. I am not sure if they are treated differently by some academicians.